# Go << and >> operators

Tags: go, bitwise-operators

Could someone please explain to me the usage of `<<` and `>>` in Go? I guess it is similar to some other languages.

Answer (score 376):

The super (possibly over) simplified definition is just that `<<` is used for "times 2" and `>>` is for "divided by 2" - and the number after it is how many times.

So `n << x` is "n times 2, x times". And `y >> z` is "y divided by 2, z times".

For example, `1 << 5` is "1 times 2, 5 times" or 32. And `32 >> 5` is "32 divided by 2, 5 times" or 1.

Comment: This is a great answer. This really solidified it in my head, thanks.

Comment: This is how answers should be.

Comment: I'm struggling to see how this will come in handy from a novice pov

Comment: This might have been just a tiny bit clearer if you explain that '2, x times' means '2, to the xth power'. Narratively the example sounds like you mean '5 instances of 2 added up', which would be 10 rather than 32.

Comment: How about `3 << 0` ?

Comment: nice answer and Peter tried to explain it from a different view, but really, if you guys think other answers are not good, please check what 'binary' is. Peter is talking about the *exact same thing* as other answers are saying. Also, there are **arithmetic shifts** and **logical shifts**. From Go spec: *"The shift operators implement arithmetic shifts if the left operand is a signed integer and logical shifts if it is an unsigned integer."*

Comment: @AllanGuwatudde, For 3 << 0, zero time. No change on the value. Output will be 3.

Comment: @AllanGuwatudde according to schemanic's comment ,which should be the right answer, 3 << 0 means '3 * 2^0'  the answer will be 3 because 2 to the power of 0 equals 1

Comment: @ChristoKiwi this question (https://exercism.org/tracks/go/exercises/grains) helped me understand it, you can equally check the community solutions too.

Answer (score 138):

From the spec at http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html, it seems that at least with integers, it's a binary shift. for example, binary 0b00001000 >> 1 would be 0b00000100, and 0b00001000 << 1 would be 0b00010000.

---

Go apparently doesn't accept the 0b notation for binary integers. I was just using it for the example. In decimal, 8 >> 1 is 4, and 8 << 1 is 16. Shifting left by one is the same as multiplication by 2, and shifting right by one is the same as dividing by two, discarding any remainder.

Comment: Great answer. It makes a lot of sense when I think that I was seeing this in code dealing with powers of 2 (1 << power = 2^power)

Comment: I think this would be the full equation: 

(x << n == x*2^n )  (x >> n == x*2^(-n))

Comment: nice answer, I binary shifting seemed troublesome at first but converting the value to decimal with powers to 2 helps well to get it

Answer (score 35):

The << and >> operators are [Go Arithmetic Operators](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Arithmetic_operators).

```
<<   left shift             integer << unsigned integer
>>   right shift            integer >> unsigned integer
```

> The shift operators shift the left
>   operand by the shift count specified
>   by the right operand. They implement
>   arithmetic shifts if the left operand
>   is a signed integer and logical shifts
>   if it is an unsigned integer. The
>   shift count must be an unsigned
>   integer. There is no upper limit on
>   the shift count. Shifts behave as if
>   the left operand is shifted n times by
>   1 for a shift count of n. As a result,
>   x << 1 is the same as x*2 and x >> 1
>   is the same as x/2 but truncated
>   towards negative infinity.

Answer (score 22):

They are basically [Arithmetic operators](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Arithmetic_operators) and its the same in other languages here is a basic PHP , C , Go Example

**GO**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var t , i uint
    t , i = 1 , 1

    for i = 1 ; i < 10 ; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("%d << %d = %d \n", t , i , t<<i)
    }


    fmt.Println()

    t = 512
    for i = 1 ; i < 10 ; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("%d >> %d = %d \n", t , i , t>>i)
    }

}
```

[GO Demo](http://play.golang.org/p/jE32sUyy-I)

**C**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

    int t = 1 ;
    int i = 1 ;

    for(i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d << %d = %d \n", t, i, t << i);
    }

        printf("\n");

    t = 512;

    for(i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d >> %d = %d \n", t, i, t >> i);
    }    

  return 0;
}
```

[C Demo](http://codepad.org/3LWcnIt9)

**PHP**

```
$t = $i = 1;

for($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) {
    printf("%d << %d = %d \n", $t, $i, $t << $i);
}

print PHP_EOL;

$t = 512;

for($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) {
    printf("%d >> %d = %d \n", $t, $i, $t >> $i);
}
```

[PHP Demo](https://eval.in/40355)

**They would all output**

```
1 << 1 = 2 
1 << 2 = 4 
1 << 3 = 8 
1 << 4 = 16 
1 << 5 = 32 
1 << 6 = 64 
1 << 7 = 128 
1 << 8 = 256 
1 << 9 = 512 

512 >> 1 = 256 
512 >> 2 = 128 
512 >> 3 = 64 
512 >> 4 = 32 
512 >> 5 = 16 
512 >> 6 = 8 
512 >> 7 = 4 
512 >> 8 = 2 
512 >> 9 = 1
```

Answer (score 14):

**n << x = n * 2^x**   *Example*: 3 << 5 = 3 * 2^5 = 96

**y >> z = y / 2^z**   *Example*: 512 >> 4 = 512 / 2^4 = 32

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 8):

`<<` is left shift.  `>>` is sign-extending right shift when the left operand is a signed integer, and is zero-extending right shift when the left operand is an unsigned integer.

To better understand `>>` think of

```
var u uint32 = 0x80000000;
var i int32 = -2;

u >> 1;  // Is 0x40000000 similar to >>> in Java
i >> 1;  // Is -1 similar to >> in Java
```

So when applied to an unsigned integer, the bits at the left are filled with zero, whereas when applied to a signed integer, the bits at the left are filled with the leftmost bit (which is 1 when the signed integer is negative as per 2's complement).

Answer (score 8):

Go's << and >> are similar to shifts (that is: division or multiplication by a power of 2) in other languages, but because Go is a safer language than C/C++ it does some extra work when the shift count is a number.

Shift instructions in x86 CPUs consider only 5 bits (6 bits on 64-bit x86 CPUs) of the shift count. In languages like C/C++, the shift operator translates into a single CPU instruction.

The following Go code

```
x := 10
y := uint(1025)  // A big shift count
println(x >> y)
println(x << y)
```

prints

```
0
0
```

while a C/C++ program would print

```
5
20
```

Comment: For C and C++ shift operators, "The behavior is undefined if the right operand is negative, or greater than or equal to the length in bits of the promoted left operand." The C and C++ standards do not guarantee that C and C++ programs will print 5 and 20.

Comment: @peterSO: Yes, you are right. My standpoint is that each programming language standard has to have a concrete implementation on a concrete CPU. In the context of a single CPU family (x86-32), the behavior of all C/C++ compilers is (can be expected to be) the same. The reason for this is that emitting exactly 1 SHL/SHR/etc instruction to implement the shift operator is the best thing that an optimizing C/C++ compiler can do when the context does not tell it anything about 'x' and 'y'. And, if the compiler knows for a fact that the code has undefined behavior, it should inform the user about it.

Comment: I disagree. You should write portable code. Both Linux and Windows run on ARM. Focusing on a single CPU family is short-sighted. Also, y is a variable. For a fact, the compiler has no knowledge of its actual runtime values.

Comment: @Atom Apart from the language providing absolutely no guarantees about what will happen, undefined behavior is likely to vary even on a single machine with a single compiler, if for example you change compilation options (eg an optimised build). Relying on it _in any way_ is dangerously wrong IMO.

Comment: @Anonymous Yes, but that is only theory. Can you provide a concrete example where changing compilation options leads to different behavior of `<<` or `>>` in C/C++?

Answer (score 7):

In **decimal math**, when we **multiply or divide by 10**, we effect the zeros on the end of the number.

In **binary**, **2** has the same effect. So we are adding a zero to the end, or removing the last digit

Answer (score 3):

<< is the bitwise left shift operator ,which shifts the bits of corresponding integer to the left….the rightmost bit being ‘0’ after the shift .

For example:

In gcc we have 4 bytes integer which means 32 bits .

like binary representation of 3 is

00000000 00000000 00000000 00000011

3<<1 would give

00000000 00000000 00000000 00000110 which is 6.

In general 1<<x would give you 2^x

In gcc

1<<20 would give 2^20 that is 1048576

but in tcc it would give you 0 as result because integer is of 2 bytes in tcc.

in simple terms we can take it like this in **golang**
So

**n << x** is "**n times 2, x times"**. And **y >> z** is "y divided by 2, z times".

**n << x = n * 2^x   Example:  3<< 5 = 3 * 2^5 = 96**

**y >> z = y / 2^z   Example: 512 >> 4 = 512 / 2^4 = 32**

Answer (score 0):

These are Right bitwise and left bitwise operators