# What does the >>= operator do

Tags: go

I was reading the implementation of sort in go, and there is this particular loop in the implementation of `func Sort(data Interface)`:

```
for i := n; i > 0; i >>= 1 {
    maxDepth++
}
```

Sort implementation : https://golang.org/src/sort/sort.go

Can someone explain to me what does the >>= operator do ?

**Edit:** It's simply a shift followed by an affectation. I think the fact it was in a loop bugged my mind.

Comment: `i >>= 1` = `i = i >> 1`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Go << and >> operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801008/go-and-operators)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `>>` operator is the right shift operator.

`>>=` is a contracted form of the right shift operator *and* assignment:

```
i >>= 1
```

It is the same as:

```
tmp := i >> 1
i = tmp
```

And that is the same thing as (without the need to create a new variable):

```
i := i >> 1
```

Answer (score 4):

Check:
https://golang.org/ref/spec

```
left shift             integer << unsigned integer

right shift            integer >> unsigned integer
```

> The shift operators shift the left operand by the shift count
>   specified by the right operand. They implement arithmetic shifts if
>   the left operand is a signed integer and logical shifts if it is an
>   unsigned integer. There is no upper limit on the shift count. Shifts
>   behave as if the left operand is shifted n times by 1 for a shift
>   count of n. As a result, x << 1 is the same as x*2 and x >> 1 is the
>   same as x/2 but truncated towards negative infinity.

Similar questions:

[Go << and >> operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801008/go-and-operators)

[double less operator in Go Tour 37](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26294372/double-less-operator-in-go-tour-37?lq=1)